# Accessing the value from a View from a particular List

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

How to fetch the values of a View in a particular List by using JQuery or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

```
    function getItemsFromView(listTitle, viewTitle) {

    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    context.load(list);
    var view = list.get_views().getByTitle(viewTitle);
    context.load(view);

    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function (sender, args) {
            var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
            query.set_viewXml("<View><Query>" + view.get_viewQuery() + "</Query></View>");

            var items = list.getItems(query);

            context.load(items);
            context.executeQueryAsync(
                function () {
                    var listEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
                    return listEnumerator; // Return List Item array
                },
                function (sender, args) { alert("error in inner request: " + args.get_message()); }
        );
        },
        function (sender, args) { alert("error: " + args.get_message()); }
    );
}

//Example of usage    
var listItems = getItemsFromView("Tasks", "My Tasks");
var i = 0;
while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    i++;
}
alert("items retrieved: " + i);
```

Here is a similiar question for your reference:

[JavaScript library to get list items based on a view using CSOM/JSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/196922/javascript-library-to-get-list-items-based-on-a-view-using-csom-jsom)